# nginx gunicorn 502 bad gateway: upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream

Tags: python, django, nginx

I have a Django app with which users can create video collages using multiple videos. Problem is, on production, when uploading videos to amazon s3, I get a 502 bad gateway (works fine locally). Does anyone know what could be wrong? I already set

```
client_max_body_size 100M
```

and

```
fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 3000;
fastcgi_send_timeout 3000;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong? Thanks in advance

Full error:

```
2017/12/31 23:50:51 [error] 1279#1279: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, 
client: 107.205.110.154, 
server: movingcollage.com, 
request: "POST /create-collage/ HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://unix:/home/mike/movingcollage/movingcollage.sock:/create-collage/", 
host: "movingcollage.com", referrer: "http://movingcollage.com/create-collage/"
```

Answer (score 7):

If the problem were in nginx timeout it would give you `504` error. `502` error means that this error could happen due to timeout in process behind nginx, gunicorn in your case I guess. Try to launch it with `-t 3000` param (to match your nginx conf).

Comment: Hi Kirill, could you please show the code? I am new to use Nginx and I have tried: `systemctl restart nginx -t 3000` which shows an error: `Unknown unit type or load state '3000s'.`